# How to get node.js to connect to mongolab using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab, database

I've been trying to use mongoose (module for node.js and mongodb). And tried to get a connection with mongolab up and running. I tried the following at the top of my app.js file, but I couldn't seem to enter the db.on function.

```
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = 'mongodb://username:password#####@ds.mongolab.com:#####/db';
global.db = mongoose.createConnection(uri);
global.Schema = mongoose.Schema;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  console.log("db up")
  var userSchema = new Schema({
      name  :  { type: String, default: '' }
    , password   :  { type: String, default: '' }
  });
  var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  var test = new userModel({name: "test", password: "test"})

  console.log("me: " + test)

  test.save(function (err, test) {
    console.log("saved?")
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("saved!")
  });

  console.log("after save");

});
```

My terminal output was

```
/usr/local/bin/node bin/www
me: { _id: 557f93a8a8b4b8628095bd01, password: 'test', name: 'test' }
after save
```

The debugger also seemed to skip the function (my debugging skills on WebStorm are limited though)

This also didn't work in a more straightforward manner:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = 'mongodb://username:password.mongolab.com:#####/db';
db = mongoose.createConnection(uri);
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var userSchema = new Schema({
      name  :  { type: String, default: '' }
    , password   :  { type: String, default: '' }
  });
  var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  var test = new userModel({name: "test", password: "test"})

  console.log("me: " + test)

  test.save(function (err, test) {
    console.log("saved?")
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("saved!")
  });
  console.log("after save");
```

This gave me the same terminal output.

I'd like to know what steps I need to take to actually start talking to my mongolab database. Also I don't see any collection created on mongolab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using

```
db = mongoose.connect(uri);
```

instead of

```
db = mongoose.createConnection(uri);
```